# Get a single line output from a batch script

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I am trying to figure out how to avoid multiple outputs when writing a batch script. At the moment I am parsing the output of an program in the following way:

```
@echo off

TYPE tmp.txt | findstr /R /C:"some_str_to_parse" > tmp2.txt
TYPE tmp2.txt | FOR /f "tokens=4" %%i in ('more') do echo %%i>tmp.txt
set /p some_var=<tmp.txt

TYPE tmp.txt | findstr /R /C:"some_str_to_parse" > tmp2.txt
TYPE tmp2.txt | FOR /f "tokens=4" %%i in ('more') do echo %%i>tmp.txt
set /p some_var2=<tmp.txt

echo %some_var% - %some_var2%
```

The problem is that I only want the echo output at the end of the script and nothing else.

What I get when calling the batch script is:

```
> echo XXX 1>tmp.txt
> echo YYY 1>tmp.txt
> echo XXX - YYY         <-- This is the only output i want
```

How can I achive this?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Forgot to mention, echo is off.

What i want is to parse the output of slik svn clients "svn info" command
to get the date and revision number in the form: YYYY-MM-DD-REVISION

The output of svn info looks like this:

```
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: .....
URL: https://www.....
Relative URL: ^/trunk
Repository Root: ......
Repository UUID: .......
Revision: 123
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: xxx
Last Changed Rev: 123
Last Changed Date: 2015-12-11 16:56:22 +0100 (Fri, 11 Dec 2015)
```

Comment: what about `@echo off`? Or if you don't want that for any reason, `... do @echo %%i>tmp.txt`

Comment: Seems overly complex to me. You don't reveal what the contents of the files is, so simplification will be elusive.

Comment: Besides the fact that your code is quite complicated, the issue comes from the pipe `|` I think, as such opens two new `cmd` instances, in which the `@echo off` in your script has no effect; so ` | @for /F` and/or `do @echo %%i` should avoid the unintended echoes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=:" %%a IN (q3426541.txt) DO (
 IF "%%a"=="Last Changed Rev" SET "rev=%%b"
 IF "%%a"=="Last Changed Date" SET "chgdate=%%b"&GOTO done
)
:done
SET "result=%chgdate:~1,10%-%rev:~1%"
ECHO %result%
GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q3426541.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Read the file, tokenising on `:`. Up to the first `:` to `%%a`, to second `:` or eol to `%%b`.

see whether the string in `%%` matches the two targets. Record the revision which occurs first in `rev` and the date data in `chgdate`. On finding the date data, terminate the loop (and hence read the file no further).

set the result to the `10` characters of `chgdate`, starting at "character 1" and sring that with a **<kbd>-</kbd>** and the revision in `rev` starting at "character 1"

Note that batch substringing is calculated from "character 0" being the first character of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=3,4 delims=: " %%a in ('find "Last Changed" tmp.txt') do set "_%%a=%%b" 
echo %_Date%-%_Rev%
```

or even better (no temp file):

```
for /f "tokens=3,4 delims=: " %%a in ('svn info^|find "Last Changed" ') do set "_%%a=%%b" 
echo %_Date%-%_Rev%
```